# Swift - UIView Animation speed up after first run

Tags: swift, swift2

I am displaying different animation for each case whereas it seem they are getting add together and speeding up. I tried using stopAnimating() as well as removeAllAnimations(). None of them are working.

```
        switch currentDrawType {
        case 0:
            for i in 0..<imageNames.count{
                images.append(UIImage(named: imageNames[i])!)
            }
            self.starImage.animationImages = images
            self.starImage.animationDuration = 0.5
        case 1:

            for a in 0..<imageA.count{
                images.append(UIImage(named: imageA[a])!)
            }
            self.starImage.animationImages = images
            self.starImage.animationDuration = 7.0
        case 2:
            for b in 0..<imageB.count{
                images.append(UIImage(named: imageB[b])!)
            }
            self.starImage.animationImages = images
            self.starImage.animationDuration = 0.5

        default:
            break
        }
```

Comment: If you need only one case happening, you need to insert `break` after each case to prevent it from going to the next one. See that's how switch statements work.

Comment: @Dershowitz123 switch cases do not fall through in swift. https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/ControlFlow.html

Comment: Yeah there's but one caveat, 
“Although break is not required in Swift, you can use a break statement to match and ignore a particular case or to break out of a matched case before that case has completed its execution. For details, see Break in a Switch Statement.”

Excerpt From: Apple Inc. “The Swift Programming Language (Swift 2.2).” iBooks. https://itun.es/in/jEUH0.l